# Android setting AndroidAnnotations using gradle at AndroidStudio not show layout

Tags: android, gradle, android-annotations

I was learning the gradle and AndroidAnnotations framework in android studio.
But I encounter the problems at the initial...= =
And then I create a new project using android studio and I added the dependences about the AndroidAnnotations.

My app.gradle is as below:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
 android {
     compileSdkVersion 22
     buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
     defaultConfig {
         applicationId "yu.idv.androidannotationtest"
         minSdkVersion 15
         targetSdkVersion 22
         versionCode 1
         versionName "1.0"
     }
     buildTypes {
         release {
             minifyEnabled false
             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),'proguard-rules.pro'
         }
     }
 }
 dependencies {
     compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
     compile 'org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:3.3.1'
 }
```

Then I put the annotation common above of the Activity like below:

```
 import org.androidannotations.annotations.EActivity;

 @EActivity(R.layout.activity_main)
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {
     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 //        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     }
```

But when I compiled my program, I couldn't see the required layout. Layout shown was default one with a "Hello world" TextView in the XML file.

What happened in my gradle or other setting in the AndroidStudio?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Remove the setContentView call, @EActivity will generate that. Also a tip : do not depend on local jars in Gradle, use proper dependency management.

Answer (score 1):

You also have to add the processor as an apt dependency and a processing argument which tells AA the location of the manifest using the android-apt plugin. Also do not forgot to change your manifest to point to the generated Activity (underscore at end).

Check out the Gradle instructions:https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Building-Project-Gradle.

Or start from the example project:https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/tree/develop/examples/gradle

So basically add these to your script, too:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
      mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.4'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-apt'
def AAVersion = '3.3.1'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
}

apt {
    arguments {
        androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0].processResources.manifestFile
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I am implementing as per your guidance but I am getting this error in AS - 3.3.1, gradle - 3.0.1 error `android-apt plugin is incompatible with the Android Gradle plugin use Please use 'annotationProcessor' configuration instead`. I have configured AP in default settings of AS but it still gives annotation related errors. Any help would be appreciated 
PS: I am total novic to android with knowledge of java only :(

Answer (score 0):

```
dependencies {
    def aaVersion = "4.7.0"

    annotationProcessor "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:${aaVersion}"
    implementation "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:${aaVersion}"
}
```

If you are using `implementation` then `annotationProcessor` is working, not `apt`.