# androidannotations 4.0.0 doesn't show layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-annotations

I am using androidannotations 4.0.0 with Android studio,

My code like this:

```
@EActivity(resName = "activity_demo_web_sdk")
public class DemoWebSdkActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    String TAG="DemoWebSdkActivity";
}
```

After I run this code,I can't see the  layout,but If I use `setContentView` rather than androidannotations, it works well.

My gradle is as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        // replace with the current version of the Android plugin
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        // replace with the current version of the android-apt plugin
        classpath 'com.neenbedankt.gradle.plugins:android-apt:1.8'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'android-apt'
def AAVersion = '4.0.0'
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    apt "org.androidannotations:androidannotations:$AAVersion"
    compile "org.androidannotations:androidannotations-api:$AAVersion"
}
apt {
    arguments {
        androidManifestFile variant.outputs[0]?.processResources?.manifestFile
        library true
        // if you have multiple outputs (when using splits), you may want to have other index than 0

        // you should set your package name here if you are using different application IDs
        // resourcePackageName "your.package.name"

        // You can set optional annotation processing options here, like these commented options:
        // logLevel 'INFO'
        // logFile '/var/log/aa.log'
    }
}
```

Anyone have idea,why it happens?

I noticed some one meet the same [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31084613/android-setting-androidannotations-using-gradle-at-androidstudio-not-show-layout),but no solve answer.

Need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is definitely one problem. You should use strings in the processing parameters:

```
library "true"
```

Also, be sure you use the generated class `DemoWebSdkActivity_` in the manifest, and also start that one.